# How to retrieve the current listeners from a wowza cloud live stream via api?

Tags: wowza

We are using the wowza cloud to run a weekly live streaming event. Is there a way to get the current listeners as live data from the api?

We found two endpoints, but they appear to be equally dysfunctional:

1. https://api.cloud.wowza.com/api/v1.4/usage/stream_targets/y7tm2dfl/live leads to

```
​{
    "meta": {
        "status": 403,
        "code": "ERR-403-RecordUnaccessible",
        "title": "Record Unaccessible Error",
        "message": "The requested resource isn't accessible.",
        "description": ""
    },
    "request_id": "def6744dc2d7a609c61f488560b80019",
    "request_timestamp": "2020-03-27T19:54:14.443Z"
}​
```

2. https://api.cloud.wowza.com/api/v1.4/usage/viewer_data/stream_targets/y7tm2dfl leads to

```
​{
    "meta": {
        "status": 404,
        "code": "ERR-404-RouteNotFound",
        "title": "Route Not Found Error",
        "message": "The requested endpoint couldn't be found.",
        "description": ""
    },
    "request_id": "11dce4349e0b97011820a39032d9664a",
    "request_timestamp": "2020-03-27T19:56:01.637Z"
}​
```

**y7tm2dfl** is one of the two stream target ids, we get from calling https://api.cloud.wowza.com/api/v1.4/live_streams/nfpvspdh/stats

Is this the right way? According to [this question](https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/50767/how-to-get-concurrent-live-viewers-via-rest-api.html?childToView=55513) the data might be only available with an delay of 2 hours...

Anybody knows of something, that can actually count as live data?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wowza Support:

The below endpoint is the correct one to use for near realtime view counts:

```
curl -H "wsc-api-key: ${WSC_API_KEY}" \
  -H "wsc-access-key: ${WSC_ACCESS_KEY}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -X "GET" \
  "https://api.cloud.wowza.com/api/v1.4/usage/stream_targets/y7tm2dfl/live"
```

It appears this stream target "y7tm2dfl" is an Akamai push and will have 2 or more hours timeframe to get results. You'll need to create a new stream target that uses Fastly to take advantage of the near realtime stats.
https://www.wowza.com/docs/add-and-manage-stream-targets-in-wowza-streaming-cloud#add-a-wowza-cdn-on-fastly-target-for-hls-playback

This will retrieve the "Current Unique Viewers", which is defined as "*the number of unique viewers for the stream in the last 90 seconds*". This is only available with Fastly Stream Targets in api 1.4.